# How to identify square wave in audio signal

Tags: fourier-transform, audio

I'm interested in identifying a square wave signal from recorded audio. This subject may be a complex problem so I would like to present the problem where I'm currently stuck at.

I recorded the audio at 44100 sampling rate, and applied FFT on the audio at the sampling rate, in ~0.1s intervals. For 10 seconds.

A 440Hz sine wave tone was generated, on and off at a 2 seconds period. For reference, below is the code to generate the tone.

```
import pysine
import time

generator = pysine.PySine()

for x in range(10):
    generator.sine(frequency=440.0, duration=1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Then the audio is recorded for analysis.

FFT is done on the audio data as described above. All of the results are then saved in a 2D array. Image below shows part of the data displayed in a grayscale image. It's corresponding data: [interesting_data](https://justpaste.it/a30k8)

[image: Frequency amplitude over time graph (400-500Hz)]

Visually there is an obvious pattern at row 40 (400 + 40 = 440Hz) because that is the tone I generated. From here the question is, how do I detect this pattern? The objective is to identify it's a square wave with 2s period, with no limit to amplitude, meaning I can only say the delta between max and min of the wave is more than an arbitrary number, I don't know the signal offset.

Am I in the right direction? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the signal is? You call it a "square wave" but what you are modeling is a modulated square wave (or sine wave, depending how you look at it). What exactly do you know about the signal and what exactly do you want to detect

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with the concept modulated square wave, but after some googling I think the signal I generated is a "On-Off Keyed Wave".

Comment: @Hilmar Continuing my previous comment, I generated a 440Hz sine wave audio, and then turned it on and off at 0.5Hz for 10 seconds. Then at the other end I recorded it. Now in the recording, that likely include noises, I would like to know if the "On-Off Keyed Wave" I generated is present or not. If yes, then what frequency is the carrier wave (should be 440Hz). I am sure that the on/off frequency is a fixed 0.5Hz.

Comment: If you know exactly the pattern you could use some cross-correlation between the known pattern and the “signal” of interest (I wouldn’t call the spectrogram of a signal, a signal itself). The peaks of the cross-correlation function will correspond to the instances where the known pattern matches exactly with the signal you have. This is used in detection theory and you can find it as matched filter.